# Android: Screen rotation causes errors when updating the screen

Tags: android

I have a problem. The basic situation: I have an application that shows two tabs. I achieve this using a ViewPager, FragmentPagerAdapter etc. I want to change the value of a few TextViews whenever the location is changed. I've attached some code snippets:

I add the tabs using the following FragmentPagerAdapter:

```
class MyAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    public Fragment getItem(int numberTabs) {
        // Assign fragments to the tabs
        Fragment contentFragment = new Fragment();
        switch(numberTabs){
        case 0:
            contentFragment = new CockpitFragment();
            break;
        case 1:
            contentFragment = new GoogleMapFragment();
            break;
        }
        return contentFragment;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        // Return the number of existing tabs
        return 2;
    }   
}
```

Now I want to change the TextViews on my CockpitFragment from my MainActivity. Therefore, I have implemented an Interface. Here is a little code snippet of the method:

```
public void updateCockpit(String a, String b) {
    FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    CockpitFragment cockpitFragment = (CockpitFragment) manager.findFragmentByTag(cockpitFragmentTAG);
    cockpitFragment.changeText(a, b);       
}
```

I call it in my MainActivity like this:

```
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    try {
        communicator.updateCockpit("a", "b");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "ERROR", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

The implementation in my Fragment looks like this:

```
public void changeText(String a, String b) {
    inputFieldA.setText(a);
    inputFieldB.setText(b);
}
```

Now, changing the values works fine **if I don't rotate the screen**. The moment I rotate the screen, my catch block is executed. However, the screen will still be updated after a while. A "workaround" is to leave the catch block empty - I'll still get the correct result. However, that's not a good solution. Does anyone have an idea why this is happening?

Comment: what is `communicator` here activity instance or fragment ?

Comment: The communicator is a class (interface) containing the abstract method "updateCockpit". It is implemented and thus defined in the MainActivity. From there, I call it in the onLocationChanged method. UpdateCockpit eventually accesses the changeText method from the Fragment.

Answer (score 0):

Reload your data in `onResume()`, because everytime that you rotate the screen the Activity or Fragmente is reloaded and the data in the view at screen are cleaned.

Comment: Yes, I know this fact, but actually there shouldn't be any problems with the values that I want to set. This problem is also caused when I hardcode some values. Or do you mean saving the whole Fragment and then reloading it in the onResume method?

Comment: I think that save the data and reload in onResume will solve your problem, but is boring to do this.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this doesn't help. I still get the error. And it doesn't really make sense to me why it's not working ...